# Is $A^2 - (0,0)$ quasicompact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is $\mathbb{A}^2 - (0,0)$ quasi-compact (in the Zariski topology)? Surely this is well known. I ask because then it would give an example of a quasi-affine scheme that is not affine.

Comment: $\mathbb{A}^2$ is a Noetherian topological space, so every subset is quasi-compact.

Comment: @Hoot Ah, thanks. A reference is p.8 of Hartshorne.